# How to restore breakpoint red dot in VS 2019 Indicator Margin

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-2019

As the title suggests, I'm missing the red dot in the indicator margin for breakpoints.  I've searched around and the only relevant questions seem to be for VS Code!

I can add, edit and remove breakpoints as usual and otherwise have normal behaviour, it just no longer shows a red dot in the indicator margin.  I've made sure this is enabled, tried disabling and re-enabling the margin, changing colours / themes and disabling extensions all to no effect.  I even get the settings and disable icon when I hover over where the red dot would be and clicking in the margin will set a breakpoint as usual.  Same behaviour in edit and debug mode, using VS 2019 16.4.4 (also tried doing these steps running as administrator)

Would really appreciate any suggestions short of reinstalling everything.

Comment: Check the settings in Options | Tools | Environment | Fonts & Colors: the display of break points can be, to a degree, customised.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Richard; I've had a look through and nothing to customise the indicator margin dot.  I don't have the issue on my Laptop so I decided to export and import on the problem system to no effect; so I'm less inclined to think it's a broken setting somewhere

Answer (score 0):

In settings look for  Glyph Margin and check it, it's work to me.